# como puedo hacer que este codigo cuando se cierre uno se cierre el otro tambien

Tags: python, python-3.x, hilos

este es el codigo para ejecutar dos scrip al mismo tiempo

```
import subprocess
    def normalplaforma():
        # Iterable con las rutas de los scripts
        scripts_paths = ("C:/Users/Rafa/Documents/python/juegosursa/pajarito/doodleJump.py","C:/Users/Rafa/Documents/python/juegosursa/pajarito/2.py")
        # Creamos cada proceso    
        procesos = [subprocess.Popen(["python", script]) for script in scripts_paths]
        # Esperamos a que todos los subprocesos terminen.
        for proceso in procesos:
            proceso.wait()
```

Comment: ???? podrias ser mas claro con tu pregunta? se cierre que otro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso, no creo que convenga usar subprocess para ejecutar tus scripts, estos pueden variar según el sistema, o si Python está en el path o no, o está instalado, etc.

Lo primero que pensé es en usar el sistema de importación de modulos de Python. Esta es la forma correcta de ejecutar un script usando otro script. Pero los modulos "se importan una vez" y es necesario borrarlos del caché para que se vuelvan a ejecutar. En ese caso, lo mejor es colocar el código a ejecutar dentro de una función.

Después, empecé a indagar entre el modulo threading y multiprocessing, y me encontré una joya llamada [concurrent.future](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/library/concurrent.futures.html), que ayuda bastante a ejecutar cosas asincronicamente, tanto con hilos como con procesos.

Este modulo ofrece un objeto ThreadPoolExecutor, a la que podemos agregar funciones a ejecutar. Cuando las agregamos con submit, se devuelve un objeto future, que nos puede indicar si la tarea sigue en ejecución o no. El resto es hacer magia con Python.

Finalmente, terminamos el proceso con la función shutdown. Le indicamos que no espere a que terminen todos los procesos con wait=False.

Los modulos y el programa principal quedan así:

**Modulo 1**

```
import time

def execute():
    time.sleep(5)
```

**Modulo 2**

```
import time

def execute():
    time.sleep(10)
```

**Principal**

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

import module1
import module2

pool = ThreadPoolExecutor()

futures = []

futures.append(pool.submit(module1.execute))
futures.append(pool.submit(module2.execute))

while all(not f.done() for f in futures):
    print("alive")
    
pool.shutdown(wait=False)
```

Comment: Tienes razón. Retiro el comentario.

Comment: tengo una duda entonces no llamo los scrip si no los meto en un metodo y llamar esos metodos nada mas

Comment: Exactamente compañero